# Have to run sudo npm install -g everytime

Tags: node.js

I am getting started on a command line application with node, i have noticed that every time i make a change to my index.js file i have to run "sudo npm install -g" to relfect the change. For example

**index.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("Hello");
```

under my **package.json**

```
"bin": {
    "movie": "index.js"
  },
```

If i run "movie" from the terminal it prints out "Hello".

Now if i were to change the print statement under index.js to say **console.log("World")** and i run "movie" from the terminal it prints outs "Hello" rather than "World". But if i do "sudo npm install -g" and then run the "movie" command, it picks up "World".

I am not sure why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) instead of `npm install`. This will create a symlink on a directory that you can use for testing as if it was intalled locally on that directory.